# Intercept Email, Copy Attachments to New Template, Send to Original Recipient

Tags: email, exchange-server, html-email, email-attachments, intercept

We have legacy, unsupported software that sends an Email in plain text to a single recipient with 1 attachment. The Email passes through Exchange.

The desired result is that the customer receives a nicer, formatted HTML-style mail message, rather than the Plain Text message.

Perhaps this isn't a job for Exchange, but it makes the most sense to me to start here.

How can I intercept this Email (The subject line is a way to identify these Emails), use the attachment in another Email Template and send this to the original recipient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to intercept the message in the Transport Pipeline if you can't change the client that is sending the message. I would start by looking a transport Agents which work on 2007,2010,2013 these can be used to capture the message that was sent then you can either drop the original or use modify the original messages while its in the Transport pipeline in exchange I'd start with something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579185(v=exchg.140).aspx

Cheers
Glen